# Why is this webwork property tag giving different date formats?

Tags: date, tomcat, webwork

I've been tasked with making some changes to an old webwork web application, and I'm stuck because I just can't get the application to behave the same in my development and test systems as it does in the production system.  I don't really know a lot about webwork and it seems hard to find good documentation online.

More specifically, there is a JSP that displays a date.  In production, the date includes the time, which is necessary, but in test only the date portion shows.

In production I get dates like this:

```
7/16/2013 11:00 AM
```

and in test I get dates like this:

```
7/16/2013
```

After a lot of digging I discovered that the production tomcat "work" folder wasn't where I thought it was and it has some `..._jsp.class` files that I guess aren't associated with the JSP files I have.  However, version control says the portion of the JSP file that prints the date hasn't changed, so I still don't understand how to fix my test system.

It is using the webwork taglib:

```
<%@ taglib uri="webwork" prefix="ww" %>
```

and displaying the dates using the `property` tag in an iterator:

```
<ww:iterator value="busySearchDTO.freetimes" status="index2">
<ww:property value="start"/>
```

`freetimes` is a `java.util.Collection` of `TimeDTO` which has this field and method:

```
  /**
   * Holds value of property start.
   */
  public java.util.Date start;

  /**
   * Getter for property start.
   * @return Value of property start.
   */
  public java.util.Date getStart() {

    return this.start;
  }
```

Any explanations or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was actually fairly mundane.

There was an `xwork-conversion.properties` file that had been deleted from and ignored in version control but was still on the server.  Somehow I missed it.  It specified a class to format `java.util.Date`s.